# White lines inside polygon google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

Hello in IE i am facing a problem in polygons or i can say in shapes.As you can see in image that White lines are appearing inside the circle.This problem is only in ie and in rest browsers every thing is fine.

[image: White lines inside the circle]

Comment: Which version of IE? Does it appear in any other version? It looks like it's related to an IE8 bug in VML rendering (which Google compensated for and may no longer need to). Related query: http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/a53203fe5513ef34

Comment: -1 for the "urgent" bit. (removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 rendering issue.i suggest you to check on google support.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to running in Quirks mode. Make sure you set a doctype on the page:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`